# Error while changing a Char field to Array Field in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to change a existing CharField in a django model (it also allows null and contains null values in db currently)

now I am trying to change it to an Array Char Field, but it throws the below error

"django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "tags" contains null values"

From

```
tags= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

To

```
tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True))
```

I have selected option 2 while before running migrate

Comment: The ArrayField needs to be nullable: `ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True), null=True, blank=True)`

Comment: @TomHamiltonStubber   thanks but now i facing issues with data , getting this error  "django.db.utils.DataError: malformed array literal" ,since that field already had some char values

Answer (score 0):

In this option 2 you selected, you were asked to select a default value yourself, right?

Add a default attribute to your model's field. The existing null values will be turned into that value, for instance:

```
tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=[]))
```

Comment: tried the above code  , but still getting the same error while running migrate